# How can I verify that a given solution of the Quantum Yang-Baxter equation is associated to a given Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, integrable-systems, yang-baxter-equations

Take, for instance, the $R$ matrix,

\begin{equation} 
R(u)=\begin{pmatrix}u+1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & u & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & u & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & u+1\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
wich satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation 
\begin{equation}
R^{12}(u-v)R^{13}(u)R^{23}(v)=R^{23}(v)R^{13}(u)R^{12}(u-v). 
\end{equation}
This $R$ matrix is associated to the $sl(2)$ Lie algebra, but how can I prove that?
Actually I have a very complicated $R$ matrix: I'm looking for a general guide to find the Lie algebra associated to a given $R$ matrix.

In other question posted here, ([Solutions of the Quantum Yang-Baxter Equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5103/solutions-of-the-quantum-yang-baxter-equation)) I found the comment: "The general theory (due to Jimbo) is that each irreducible finite dimensional representation of the quantised enveloping algebra of a Kac-Moody algebra (not of finite type) gives a trigonometric R-matrix." I think I'm looking for the converse of this: given a $R$-matrix satisfying the Yang-Baxter equation, what is the Lie algebra associated to it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From a solution of the TB equation you can construct an algebra, using the FRT construction. But that algebra willin general not come from a Lie algebra in any reasonable way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is a very hard problem and the answer to this question is, unfortunately, open.

A famous example that illustrates this in the context of quantum integrability comes from the one-dimensional [Hubbard model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model) in condensed-matter physics. Its (quite complicated) $R$-matrix was known since the late eighties, yet the corresponding quantum group was only found in the last decade, "by accident" in a *very* different context. Namely: the $R$-matrix of the Hubbard model came out of the study of the quantum group associated to a Lie (super)algebra, and the choice of the latter was motivated by string theory (more precisely: the AdS/CFT correspondence). For a bit more about this, and further references, see for example (the introduction of) [arXiv:1509.06205](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06205).